# TypeError: argument 1 must be read-only bytes-like object, not memoryview

Tags: python, numpy, buffer, typeerror, memoryview

I am updating a library from Python 2 to Python 3.7 that takes sound input from the microphone and converts it into musical pitch. However, I get this error when I run the program:

`File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/analyse.py", line 58, in detect_pitch
    dp = analyseffi.detect_pitch(chunk2, min_frequency, max_frequency, samplerate, sens, ratio)
TypeError: argument 1 must be read-only bytes-like object, not memoryview`

It seems to have to do with the following piece of code:

```
# Read raw microphone data
rawsamps = stream.read(1024)
# Convert raw data to NumPy array
samps = numpy.frombuffer(rawsamps, dtype=numpy.int16)
# Show the volume and pitch
print(analyse.musical_detect_pitch(samps))
```

Where `chunk2` in the error message is obtained by taking `chunk2 = samps.data[:]` within the function. I've been trying to figure out how to solve the error, but based on my limited understanding, "read-only bytes-like object"s are very similar to "memoryview". So I'm unsure what I should do to convert from one to the other.

Comment: The function does not like the first argument to be a numpy array. Try `rawsamps` instead!

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for the suggestion, it was the start of me solving the error. However, now it's giving me note names exactly one octave below what they should be—but that could be caused by many other things!